# Auto-scheduling not working in gantt chart dhtmlx

Tags: javascript, jquery, scheduled-tasks, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

Is there are any possibilities to add auto-scheduling in gantt chart standard edition from [this](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/pro) link?

Because I am working on standard edition when I am including `dhtmlxgantt_auto_scheduling.js` it shows me error Gantt is not defined in `dhtmlxgantt_auto_scheduling.js`.

I am stuck at auto scheduling the link tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short:** Auto scheduling extension is not included into GPL version of the gantt, so the reliable approaches for getting this functionality are to either implement auto scheduling manually or to get a package that includes that extension.

As for the extensions and packages in general,
there are four bundles of dhtmlxGantt:

1. GPL (Standard Edition)
2. Commercial
3. Enterprise
4. Evaluation

Extensions are generally not cross-compatible between packages. On practice, it means that

- extensions from an Evaluation and Enterprise packages (3,4) usually won't work with dhtmlx gantt core from GPL or Commercial versions (1,2).
- extensions from a Commercial or a GPL edition may work with Enterprise/Evaluation gantt core, but the correct work is not guaranteed.

GPL package does not contain extension marked as 'Available only in PRO Edition' https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__auto_scheduling.html
So you can either obtain a package that includes all needed features or implement needed functionality yourself.

Comment: https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/abb0f9b1

In this link autoscheduling is working only with the parent, If my task are linked like : T1->T2->T3->T4
as it for now autoschedule will only work when we drag T1. But I want if we drag T2 so T3 and T4 should also be auto scheduled.

Can it be possible? And how ?

Comment: it's possible - all tasks and links between them are available from public API, so you can implement everything that is done by auto scheduling extension. Have you checked this article https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__dragging_dependent_tasks.html#movingtasksmanually ? It seems to be pretty close to what you need